# How to take a screen shot of a region of the screen with Gnome 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

Compiz embarked tools which permitted selecting a region of the screen and copying the snapshot to the clipboard. I miss that on Gnome 3. Is there any way to do so?
I’ve seen that **Alt+PrintScr** took a screenshot of the focussed window but that’s not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) has a commandline program `import` that allows you to do that. E.g. do `import screenshot.png` and the cursor will change and allow you to either click to capture the selected window or select a region to capture the region and save it in `screenshot.png`.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Ubuntu with Gnome3 and noticed that <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> does the trick. I have **`gnome-screenshot`** installed, not sure if it's that providing the functionality.

Comment: to me it is the best solution for GNOME as it elegantly capture pretty much everything of `gnome-shell` including transparency, effects

Comment: It is perferct for gnome user